# python's weird behaivor of evaluating the arithmetic expression(5-1//2)

Tags: python

```
print(5-1//2)
```

This expression gives the result 5

How ?

my try:

```
x=5-1//2
x=5-1 #(-1//2 gives -1)
x=4
```

but python is saying 5

how?

Comment: because `1//2 == 0` - reading the docs about operator precedence might shed a light on your problem.

Comment: BTW the tags `python-3.x` `and python-2.7` are not relevant for this question.

Comment: The ``-`` in ``5-1//2`` is a *binary* ``-``. What you have checked with ``-1//2`` is a *unary* ``-``. These have different precedence. The way you separated ``5-1//2`` into ``5(-1//2)`` is not how it is actually evaluated.

Comment: that is the floor division operator, its just the quotient without the remainder, since the (  1-(2*0)) is less than 2, therefore its the remainder..

Comment: see [python operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)

Comment: @PsychopathicAzula Hmm, took me longer than expected to find an error on that page, about 20 seconds.

Comment: @PsychopathicAzula That's really not helpful. It doesn't even cover unary operators, which are critical to understand the error here. (It doesn't help that it's wrong to boot – assignment isn't an operator.)

Comment: @Psychopathic W3Schools is terrible for Python. For example, membership and identity are comparisons. See the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i checked -1//2 ,it gives -1 only

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "assignment isn't an operator" - Then again... ["the assignment operator"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I see I should be more precise next time… noted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There are lots of other issues, though :-). For example describing `and` with "Returns True if both statements are true" contains *two* errors. And describing `in` with "Returns True if a sequence with the specified value is present in the object" sounds backwards at best.

Comment: @wjandrea ik but thy hv the `try it` button—

Comment: well then, check out [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators) they provide nice demonstrations and explain it very clearly... (i taught myself java, c++, python entirely from there)

Comment: @PsychopathicAzula That link has largely the same information. Explaining things clearly isn't all that useful if these things are subtly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `-` in `5-1//2` is a *binary* `-`. What you have checked with `-1//2` is a *unary* `-`. These have different [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The way you separated `5-1//2` into `5+(-1//2)` is not how it is actually evaluated.

*-- [comment](/questions/69212734/#comment122330718_69212734) by [MisterMiyagi](/users/5349916/mistermiyagi), with math corrected and link added*

Comment: The ``5(-1//2)`` was actually to show how the separation doesn't make sense. :P

Comment: It's not about precedence. Precedence tells you what gets evaluated first when both are there. But there's only one here.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It is; binary ``-`` and unary ``-`` have different precedence wrt ``//``. The ``-`` in ``5-1//2`` applies to the entire ``1//2``. The ``-`` in ``-1//2`` applies only to the ``1``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I thought that was what you were going for, but it didn't make sense with OP's expectations since `5(-1)` is -5.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm talking about what the answer says, precedence of binary and unary `-`. Only one of them is here.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode One of ``-`` *and ``//``* is there.

Comment: @don Yes, exactly. OP mistook the binary one for the unary one.